# How to convert a string to a nested list?

Tags: python, json, list, split, element

I'm trying to convert a string into a nested list so that I can select elements based on the date. This is the string I'm trying to convert:

`{"data":[[[""],["2,681,118"]],[[""],["529,106"]],[[""],["1402"]],[[""],["33"]],[["","Positivas","Total Px Ag"],["30/07/2020","216","811"],["31/07/2020","316","1,176"],["01/08/2020","383","1,461"],["02/08/2020","529","2,153"],["03/08/2020","635","2,582"],["04/08/2020","1060","3,859"],["05/08/2020","1798","6,143"],["06/08/2020","2597","8,947"],["07/08/2020","3504","12,063"],["08/08/2020","3940","13,713"],["09/08/2020","4869","16,480"],["10/08/2020","5489","18,279"],["11/08/2020","6557","21,555"],["12/08/2020","8,028","28,212"],["13/08/2020","9,190","32,216"],["14/08/2020","10,477","37,026"],["15/08/2020","11,672","41,619"],["16/08/2020","13483","47,399"],["17/08/2020","13,904","49,031"],["18/08/2020","14,886","52,631"],["19/08/2020","17,264","59,726"],["20/08/2020","18,889","65,451"],["21/08/2020","19,958","69,605"],["22/08/2020","21,827","76,373"],["23/08/2020","22,126","77,525"],["24/08/2020","23,096","81,031"],["25/08/2020","24,854","87,281"],["26/08/2020","26,256","93,182"],["27/08/2020","28,024","100,223"],["28/08/2020","29,657","107,145"],["29/08/2020","30,815","112,531"],["30/08/2020","31,527","115,888"],["31/08/2020","32,923","121,165"],["01/09/2020","34,714","129,405"],["02/09/2020","33499","127,851"],["03/09/2020","35944","138,124"],["04/09/2020","37,387","145,603"],["05/09/2020","38,945","153,238"],["06/09/2020","40,005","157,962"],["07/09/2020","41,770","166,722"],["08/09/2020","44,200","177,432"],["09/09/2020","45,646","185,245"],["10/09/2020","47,578","194,561"],["11/09/2020","49,331","203,685"],["12/09/2020","50,739","211,517"],["13/09/2020","51,393","216,127"],["14/09/2020","53,298","223,942"],["15/09/2020","52,289","219,189"],["16/09/2020","53,852","228,420"],["17/09/2020","59,212","254,698"],["18/09/2020","61,373","266,762"],["19/09/2020","63,192","276,724"],["20/09/2020","63,730","281,095"],["21/09/2020","65,454","288,294"],["22/09/2020","67,645","300,123"],["23/09/2020","70,510","313,522"],["24/09/2020","72,931","326,878"],["25/09/2020","74,790","338,618"],["26/09/2020","76,636","350,286"],["27/09/2020","78,231","359,259"],["28/09/2020","79,437","365,650"],["29/09/2020","81,885","378,445"],["30/09/2020","83,536","390,591"],["01/10/2020","86,581","405,469"],["02/10/2020","88,769","419,606"],["03/10/2020","91,497","435,562"],["04/10/2020","92,084","440,129"],["05/10/2020","94,756","452,541"],["06/10/2020","97,219","466,283"],["07/10/2020","99,131","478,478"],["08/10/2020","102,944","497,369"],["09/10/2020","105,924","514,140"],["10/10/2020","108,272","529,318"],["11/10/2020","109,143","534,885"],["12/10/2020","110,292","541,041"],["13/10/2020","113,088","553,014"],["14/10/2020","115,871","568,193"],["15/10/2020","119,985","589,861"],["16/10/2020","122,887","607,628"],["17/10/2020","125,662","622,663"],["18/10/2020","126,524","628,207"],["19/10/2020","128,042","634,754"],["20/10/2020","132,948","659,212"],["21/10/2020","134,937","671,911"],["22/10/2020","139,006","692,615"],["23/10/2020","141,844","709,412"],["24/10/2020","143,776","723,858"],["25/10/2020","144,928","730,451"],["26/10/2020","147,171","741,252"],["27/10/2020","151,468","763,433"],["28/10/2020","154,747","782,588"],["29/10/2020","159302","808,677"],["30/10/2020","161,072","821,999"],["31/10/2020","165,523","846,676"],["01/11/2020","166,657","854,868"],["02/11/2020","167,767","860,221"],["03/11/2020","170,233","872,346"],["04/11/2020","173,729","889,779"],["05/11/2020","176,857","907,448"],["06/11/2020","179,743","934,226"],["07/11/2020","183,321","955,354"],["08/11/2020","184,537","962,916"],["09/11/2020","187,051","975,475"],["10/11/2020","191,016","997,206"],["11/11/2020","193,963","1,015,733"],["12/11/2020","197,760","1,037,854"],["13/11/2020","201,044","1,060,786"],["14/11/2020","203,525","1,078,140"],["15/11/2020","204356","1,083,983"],["16/11/2020","205,248","1,088,192"],["17/11/2020","207,495","1,101,771"],["18/11/2020","211,224","1,122,018"],["19/11/2020","214,894","1,144,216"],["20/11/2020","218,099","1,164,807"],["21/11/2020","221,435","1,193,479"],["22/11/2020","222,343","1,199,903"],["23/11/2020","224,953","1,213,335"],["24/11/2020","228,343","1,232,205"],["25/11/2020","232,075","1,255,370"],["26/11/2020","236,580","1,282,888"],["27/11/2020","238,742","1,301,977"],["28/11/2020","241,835","1,322,140"],["29/11/2020","243,964","1,333,756"],["30/11/2020","245,597","1,343,739"],["01/12/2020","248,976","1,364,088"],["02/12/2020","251,596","1,384,223"],["03/12/2020","255,977","1,409,778"],["04/12/2020","260,859","1,435,230"],["05/12/2020","264,292","1,456,665"],["06/12/2020","265,698","1,466,555"],["07/12/2020","268,132","1,480,322"],["08/12/2020","271,505","1,499,624"],["09/12/2020","273,014","1,508,962"],["10/12/2020","277,248","1,532,527"],["11/12/2020","280,562","1,553,248"],["12/12/2020","286,577","1,582,159"],["13/12/2020","288,254","1,591,666"],["14/12/2020","293,324","1,615,371"],["15/12/2020","299,386","1,647,621"],["16/12/2020","304,702","1,677,361"],["17/12/2020","309,972","1,703,326"],["18/12/2020","316,089","1,731,954"],["19/12/2020","320,504","1,756,153"],["20/12/2020","322,565","1,768,605"],["21/12/2020","326,604","1,787,468"],["22/12/2020","332,330","1,814,071"],["23/12/2020","338,515","1,844,256"],["24/12/2020","344,311","1,873,102"],["25/12/2020","347,499","1,887,804"],["26/12/2020","349,152","1,896,298"],["27/12/2020","351,712","1,908,303"],["28/12/2020","354,848","1,923,669"],["29/12/2020","363,515","1,954,539"],["30/12/2020","371,194","1,987,732"],["31/12/2020","382,967","2,037,256"],["1/1/2021","387,062","2,053,280"],["2/1/2021","389,319","2,063,758"],["3/1/2021","391,354","2,071,114"],["4/1/2021","396,447","2,087,535"],["5/1/2021","405,866","2,119,794"],["6/1/2021","414,825","2,153,320"],["7/1/2021","423,586","2,188,409"],["8/1/2021","431,978","2,221,398"],["9/1/2021","438,920","2,249,492"],["10/1/2021","441,998","2,262,943"],["11/1/2021","445,210","2,272,778"],["12/1/2021","449,461","2,289,403"],["13/1/2021","454,567","2,310,220"],["14/1/2021","466,857","2,357,299"],["15/1/2021","478,666","2,398,159"],["16/1/2021","485577","2,429,571"],["17/1/2021","487,652","2,440,201"],["18/1/2021","491,243","2,456,218"],["19/1/2021","495,130","2,486,224"],["20/1/2021","501,678","2,517,951"],["21/1/2021","506,367","2,545,628"],["22/1/2021","512,457","2,578,198"],["23/1/2021","516,896","2,604,423"],["24/1/2021","518,529","2,617,046"],["25/1/2021","521,152","2,630,948"],["26/1/2021","524,884","2,653,596"],["27/1/2021","529,106","2,681,118"],["28/1/2021","","0"],["29/1/2021","","0"],["30/1/2021","","0"],["31/1/2021","","0"],["1/2/2021","","0"],["2/2/2021","","0"],["3/2/2021","","0"],["4/2/2021","","0"],["5/2/2021","","0"],["6/2/2021","","0"],["7/2/2021","","0"]]],"fileName":"titulos_antigenos","sheetNames":["total","positivas","ips","departamentos","Histórico"],"version":"57","refreshed":1611777255000}`

I've tried using the split() method but it doesn't work. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. Look at the actual data: that's not a `repr` of a Python dictionary.

Comment: Next time, please consider posting your code as a [**minimum** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. minimal input data. "*I've tried using the split() method*" please be more specific. "*it doesn't work*" please be more specific

Answer (score 1):

That's literally valid JSON. This works:

```
import json

my_string = '{"data":[[[""],["2,681,118"]], ...}'

nested_dict = json.loads(my_string)
```

Comment: Oops, thanks @Cireo.